# How to post dynamic pages?

Tags: php, javascript

I use a httpxmlpost function to load static html pages while being on my index.php.
Now I'd need to load a html dynamic page which calls a javascript file while remaining on index.php. Is it possible? How can I do?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: No, but if the maker of the site plans for pre-js browsers, you can change your header and load a normal page.

Comment: http://dma.ing.uniroma1.it/users/sasa/public/groups/SapienzaFlightTeam/dbf2013/index.php (my index)

  http://dma.ing.uniroma1.it/users/sasa/public/groups/SapienzaFlightTeam/dbf2013/competizioni.htm (my dynamic page ^^")

Comment: Just working on it, I'm about to upload I will let you know soon :D

Comment: It seems to be ok, thanks again :P